# LWJGL Pixel format not accelerated after export but not before (Libs and Natives included)

Tags: java, lwjgl

So after exporting my LWJGL game I get the following error.

```
Fri Oct 02 20:40:01 AEST 2015 INFO: LWJGL Version: 8.15.10.2900
Fri Oct 02 20:40:01 AEST 2015 INFO: Width: 1024
Fri Oct 02 20:40:01 AEST 2015 INFO: Width: 576
Failed to create Display.
org.lwjgl.LWJGLException: Pixel format not accelerated
        at org.lwjgl.opengl.WindowsPeerInfo.nChoosePixelFormat(Native Method)
        at org.lwjgl.opengl.WindowsPeerInfo.choosePixelFormat(WindowsPeerInfo.java:52)
        at org.lwjgl.opengl.WindowsDisplay.createWindow(WindowsDisplay.java:252)
        at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.createWindow(Display.java:306)
        at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:848)
        at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:757)
        at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:739)
        at com.base.engine.rendering.Window.CreateWindow(Window.java:36)
        at com.base.engine.core.CoreEngine.CreateWindow(CoreEngine.java:27)
        at com.base.game.Main.main(Main.java:8)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: No OpenGL context found in the current thread.
        at org.lwjgl.opengl.GLContext.getCapabilities(GLContext.java:124)
        at org.lwjgl.opengl.GL20.glCreateProgram(GL20.java:253)
        at com.base.engine.rendering.resourceManagement.ShaderResource.<init>(ShaderResource.java:35)
        at com.base.engine.rendering.Shader.<init>(Shader.java:55)
        at com.base.engine.rendering.RenderingEngine.<init>(RenderingEngine.java:52)
        at com.base.engine.core.CoreEngine.CreateWindow(CoreEngine.java:28)
        at com.base.game.Main.main(Main.java:8)
```

Yet I don't get it in Eclipse.
I've included the native and libs.

I'm currently using this from the Command Prompt to start the game.

```
java -Djava.library.path=(natives location) -jar game.jar 1024 576 60
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright I've worked out the problem. LWJGL doesn't seem to work in java 8. My eclipse workspace was configured to use Java 7 so it launched.

I ended up using

```
@echo off
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\java.exe" %*
```

and saving it as java7.bat then I used the word java7 instead of java and it worked.